# Running of procedure takes a long time

Tags: excel, vba

Here my code:

```
Private Sub CopyRanges()

Sheets("Test2").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("A"), ActiveSheet.Columns("A").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(2), Sheets("Test1").Columns(2).End(xlDown)).Value

Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("B"), ActiveSheet.Columns("B").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(23), Sheets("Test1").Columns(23).End(xlDown)).Value

Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("C:D"), ActiveSheet.Columns("C:D").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(3), Sheets("Test1").Columns(3).End(xlDown)).Value

Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("E:F"), ActiveSheet.Columns("E:F").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(4), Sheets("Test1").Columns(4).End(xlDown)).Value

Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("G:H"), ActiveSheet.Columns("G:H").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(5), Sheets("Test1").Columns(5).End(xlDown)).Value

Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("I:J"), ActiveSheet.Columns("I:J").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(6), Sheets("Test1").Columns(6).End(xlDown)).Value

Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("K:L"), ActiveSheet.Columns("K:L").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(7), Sheets("Test1").Columns(7).End(xlDown)).Value

Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("M:N"), ActiveSheet.Columns("M:N").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(8), Sheets("Test1").Columns(8).End(xlDown)).Value

Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("O:P"), ActiveSheet.Columns("O:P").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(9), Sheets("Test1").Columns(9).End(xlDown)).Value

Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("Q:R"), ActiveSheet.Columns("Q:R").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(10), Sheets("Test1").Columns(10).End(xlDown)).Value

Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("S:T"), ActiveSheet.Columns("S:T").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(11), Sheets("Test1").Columns(11).End(xlDown)).Value

Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("U:V"), ActiveSheet.Columns("U:V").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(12), Sheets("Test1").Columns(12).End(xlDown)).Value

Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("W:X"), ActiveSheet.Columns("W:X").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(13), Sheets("Test1").Columns(13).End(xlDown)).Value

Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("Y:Z"), ActiveSheet.Columns("Y:Z").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(14), Sheets("Test1").Columns(14).End(xlDown)).Value

Dim rCell As Range

Dim rRng As Range

    For Each rCell In Range("C1:D800")

        If rCell.Value = "Maximum accomodation in room is" Then

            If rRng Is Nothing Then

                Set rRng = rCell

            Else

                Set rRng = Application.Union(rRng, rCell)

            End If

        End If

    Next

    rRng.Offset(, 0).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Unmerge
    Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral

    Columns("A").Replace What:=",99", Replacement:="", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Columns("A").Replace What:=",00", Replacement:="", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

   Range("B5").Select

   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   Application.Run "ResizeAll"

End Sub
```

Vba works well except for timing. Procedure takes between 7-10 minutes and could not find a solution to reduce the time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I guess that all the columns need to be expanded until the same row right? Then you could get the lastRow of your data first and this way avoid .End(xlDown) so many times

Comment: Yes, right to be expanded until same row

Answer (score 0):

As an example of my suggestion I adapted the first row, you could try this out, I hope it will improve your code's performance.

```
Test2LastRow =Sheets("Test2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Test1LastRow =Sheets("Test1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Test2").Range("A1:A" & Test2LastRow & "").Value = Sheets("Test1").Range("B1:B" & Test1LastRow & "").Value
```

Comment: I applied but debug as "Object Variable or block variable not set" at this line

rRng.Offset(, 0).Select

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to follow what your code is doing - rearranging columns and duplicating some of them?  Seems Test2 columns C & D are equal to Test1 column 3?

I found some code which looks like it could speed things up (https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/606890-reorder-columns-using-macro.html)

Using this method to sort your columns into the desired order, and using FIND rather than looping through each cell:

```
Private Sub CopyRanges()

    Dim NewColOrder As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim FirstFound As String
    Dim rRng As Range

    'This is the order you want the columns in.
    'So the 26th column should be in position 2.
    'Column 3 is repeated twice:  Columns("C:D") = Columns(3) in your code.
    NewColOrder = Array(1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 11, 11, 13, 13, 15, 15, 17, 17, 19, 19, 21, 21, 23, 23, 25, 25, 2)

    With ThisWorkbook
        With .Worksheets("Test1")

            'Create copies of repeated columns.
            For x = LBound(NewColOrder) + 1 To UBound(NewColOrder)
                If NewColOrder(x) = NewColOrder(x - 1) Then
                    .Columns(NewColOrder(x)).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                    .Columns(NewColOrder(x) - 1).Copy Destination:=.Columns(NewColOrder(x))
                End If
            Next x

            'Add a new row and put desired column order in row.
            .Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
            .Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(NewColOrder) + 1) = NewColOrder

            'Find the last cell containing data.
            Set rLastCell = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)

            'Sort the data into the correct column order.
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), rLastCell).Sort .Cells(1), 1, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight

            'Copy the data over to Test1.
            .Range(.Cells(2, 1), rLastCell).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test2").Range("A1")
        End With

        'Now to find "Maximum accomodation in room is"
        With .Worksheets("Test2")

            'Find the last cell containing data.
            Set rLastCell = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)

            With .Range(.Cells(3, 1), rLastCell)
                Set rFound = .Find("Maximum accomodation in room is", LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                    FirstFound = rFound.Address
                    Do
                        If rRng Is Nothing Then
                            Set rRng = rFound
                        Else
                            Set rRng = Union(rRng, rFound)
                        End If
                        Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
                    Loop While rFound.Address <> FirstFound
                End If

                'Not quite sure what you're trying to do here.
                If Not rRng Is Nothing Then
                    rRng.EntireRow.UnMerge
                    rRng.HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                End If
            End With

            .Columns(1).Replace What:=",99", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
            .Columns(1).Replace What:=",00", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart

        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code created dublicates. Test1 includes my row data without an order so the vba takes test1 datas into test2 reorganized. I put links of test1, test2 (my code) & test2 (your code) below to clarify:

https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/BjE3

https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/BjEL

https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/BjEW

Comment: I thought that was what your code does.  `Range(ActiveSheet.Columns("C:D"), ActiveSheet.Columns("C:D").End(xlDown)).Value = Range(Sheets("Test1").Columns(3), Sheets("Test1").Columns(3).End(xlDown)).Value`  Doesn't this take column 3 and place it in columns C:D?

Comment: My code copies test1 column3 value into C:D (merged) columns in test2 sheet. My 3rd party agency program can read the datas by this way only. Test1 is my contract design but I must rearrange it in test2 to be read by agency software

Answer (score 0):

I changed the 1st part of my code and now working much more faster than previous:

Private Sub CopyRanges()

Dim wsTest2 As Worksheet, wsTest1 As Worksheet

Dim lr As Long

Set wsTest2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test2")

Set wsTest1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test1")

With Application

```
.ScreenUpdating = False

.DisplayAlerts = False
```

End With

wsTest2.Activate

lr = wsTest1.UsedRange.Rows(wsTest1.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

wsTest2.Range("A1:A" & lr).Value = wsTest1.Range("B1:B" & lr).Value

wsTest2.Range("B1:B" & lr).Value = wsTest1.Range("W1:W" & lr).Value

wsTest2.Range("C1:D" & lr).Value = wsTest1.Range("C1:C" & lr).Value

wsTest2.Range("E1:F" & lr).Value = wsTest1.Range("D1:D" & lr).Value

wsTest2.Range("G1:H" & lr).Value = wsTest1.Range("E1:E" & lr).Value

wsTest2.Range("I1:J" & lr).Value = wsTest1.Range("F1:F" & lr).Value

wsTest2.Range("K1:L" & lr).Value = wsTest1.Range("G1:G" & lr).Value

wsTest2.Range("M1:N" & lr).Value = wsTest1.Range("H1:H" & lr).Value

wsTest2.Range("O1:P" & lr).Value = wsTest1.Range("I1:I" & lr).Value

wsTest2.Range("Q1:R" & lr).Value = wsTest1.Range("J1:J" & lr).Value

wsTest2.Range("S1:T" & lr).Value = wsTest1.Range("K1:K" & lr).Value

wsTest2.Range("U1:V" & lr).Value = wsTest1.Range("L1:L" & lr).Value

wsTest2.Range("W1:X" & lr).Value = wsTest1.Range("M1:M" & lr).Value

wsTest2.Range("Y1:Z" & lr).Value = wsTest1.Range("N1:N" & lr).Value

'and so on...

End Sub